# How to shorten the number of bits to represent a character sequence

Tags: javascript, string, bit-manipulation

Given I want to store an ID that is 64 characters long, and it chooses its characters from a set of `n` characters (say `26` lowercase characters for this example, but could be any number `n`). The question is (a) what the shortest number of bits `b` I can encode this in is, and (b) how I can any character sequence of length `n` using that number of bits `b`. So specifically, if I have an alphabet of 26 characters (`n`) and I want to have a string that is 64 characters long (`m`), how many bits can you compact it down into? Given there could be any sequence of characters in the set `26^64`. More generally, in the set `n^m`, what approach can be taken to shrink the number of bits required to represent this number? I am imagining some magic like [VLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity). In this question I would prefer an approach that kept every number using the same number of bits, but in a future question I might modify this question and make the encoding an arbitrary length depending on the number. But for this question, any 64-character ID made from the alphabet `a-z`, how short can you encode it *so that every shortened string/bit-sequence is the same number of bits*?

So for example:

```
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
```

64 characters from the set `a-z`. I could encode it as:

```
16abcd
```

where it means `16 x abcd`. But this only works for repeated 4-character sequences. (Just a quick made up example). For an arbitrary sequence like:

```
wckdrwncwkdcwjdncjdjwcjwjncdjwwckdrwncwkdcwjdncjdjwcjwjncdjwkwlp
```

How can you shorten it into some smaller number of bits? Such that every sequence of 64-characters shortens to the same number of bits. If it helps, assume the alphabet to pick the characters from is *shorter* than the size in characters of the ID (64 in this case). But it would be nice to know how to do this for character sets longer than the sequence (so 52 character alphabet, 16 characters in length, type thing). Ideally the explanation would use JavaScript or something like it to demonstrate :) I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: 64 lowercase characters could be transformed to fit in 38 bytes (every time), is that what you mean? That's just a base conversion

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd have to see, it sounds like it would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind going through a BigInt (avoiding it is tricky, but possible), it could be done like this:

```
function convert(s) {
    console.assert(s.length == 64);
    // convert the string to a BigInt
    var val = 0n;
    for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        val = val * 26n + BigInt(s.charCodeAt(i) - 0x61);
    // convert the BigInt to bytes
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(38);
    for (var i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
        bytes[i] = Number(val & 0xFFn);
        val >>= 8n;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Essentially this parses the string as a base-26 number (in the normal order), then breaks it down into a base-256 number (with the least significant byte first). So for example:

```
convert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") =
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
convert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab") =
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
...
convert("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzy") =
    [254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 241, 228, 56, 161, 115, 35, 152, 36, 64, 88, 48, 43, 115, 134, 63, 100, 222, 5, 194, 138, 113, 20, 60, 164, 54, 17, 7, 104, 28]
convert("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz") =
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 241, 228, 56, 161, 115, 35, 152, 36, 64, 88, 48, 43, 115, 134, 63, 100, 222, 5, 194, 138, 113, 20, 60, 164, 54, 17, 7, 104, 28]
```

Comment: @LancePollard you're already on the right way, right? You mentioned 26^64 and n^m, that's exactly right. The next step is, the character sequences don't just come out of a set of that size, they map 1-to-1 to integers in the range 0 to n^m (exclusive), and the way to convert them is just parsing a base-n number (you know how to parse base-10, right? then replace 10 by n). Then the conversion to base-256 is the same sort of deal as converting a number to a decimal string, but again replace 10 by 256 (and I replaced modulo by bitwise AND and division by shift right, it's nicer)

Comment: I meant how did you learn so much about these topics, it is such a hard area!

Comment: Thank you for all your help too!